# A simple tutorial on how to use fessler NUFFT toolbox for motion correction?

Tags: nonuniform

I am trying to use Jeffrey Fessler's NUFFT toolbox to get a nonuniform  DFT matrix with a trajectory corresponding to a known rotation so as to correct this rotation.
I downloaded this toolbox:

[https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~fessler/code/](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Efessler/code/)

https://github.com/JeffFessler/mirt

However, I cannot find a simple and clear tutorial allowing to understand exactly what/how to pass trajectories to these functions. I think I should use nufft_adj but not sure and the demo by calling simply nufft_adj() without parameters crashed (some unknown internal variables).

Does anyone have a piece of code showing how to use this?
E.g. a corrupted DFT (i.e. some rows correspond to rotations in image space), then a code showing how to pass this information to some fessler's nufft functions and to (iteratively?) correct them?